# Starter spells for Wizard and Cleric in Starter Set sheet

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, lost-mine-of-phandelver

Just trying to make my first sessions as friendly as possible.

Would any have the Wizard and Clerics starter spells in one pdf or sheet for the characters from the starter set, lost mine of phandelver.

I know there are apps available but would love to have a physical copy, before I start scanning and snipping the book.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. The [tour], [help], [ask] and [answer] sections provide guidance on how to get the best out of an SE site.  [resource requests / shopping questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) usually get closed due to SE (the company) conventions / requirements.  Rules is rules.  Hope your session goes well, and Happy Gaming.

Comment: Iirc the available spells in the starter set are all in the [Basic Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf), which can be printed and copied for personal use

Answer (score -1):

Page three of WotC's character sheet (available [here](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/5E_CharacterSheet_Fillable.pdf)) is a spell sheet you can fill in yourself. If you google *5e spell sheet* you will find countless versions people have made themselves. Find your favourite, fill it out and print it.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a look, the characters and spells are pretty set just wondering if someone had a cheat sheet already